Find remaining queens for nqueens problem
As the title says, I have to find the remaining queens for the nqueens problem, but I have not use recursive calls and I have to use stacks and backtracking. Currently I have:
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAX_N 11

typedef struct {
    int row;
    int col;
} Queen;

typedef struct {
    int top;
    Queen items[MAX_N];
} Stack;

void initStack(Stack* stack) {
    stack->top = -1;
}

void push(Stack* stack, Queen queen) {
    if (stack->top < MAX_N - 1) {
        stack->top++;
        stack->items[stack->top] = queen;
    }
}

Queen pop(Stack* stack) {
    if (stack->top >= 0) {
        stack->top--;
        return stack->items[stack->top];
    }
    Queen emptyQueen = { -1, -1 }; // Return an invalid queen
    return emptyQueen;
}

// Helper function to check if a queen can be placed at (row, col)
bool isValid(Queen queens[], int numQueens, int row, int col) {
    for (int i = 0; i < numQueens; i++) {
        if (queens[i].row == row || queens[i].col == col ||
            queens[i].row - queens[i].col == row - col ||
            queens[i].row + queens[i].col == row + col) {
            return false; // Queens attack each other
        }
    }
    return true;
}

void solveQueens(int max_queens, Queen* initQs, int numInitQ) {
    Queen queens[MAX_N];
    Stack stack;
    initStack(&stack);

    // Initialize with initial queens
    for (int i = 0; i < numInitQ; i++) {
        queens[i] = initQs[i];
    }

    int numQueens = numInitQ;
    int row = numInitQ; // Start from the next row

    while (numQueens < max_queens) {
        bool found = false;
        for (int col = 0; col < max_queens; col++) {
            if (isValid(queens, numQueens, row, col)) {
                queens[numQueens] = (Queen){ row, col };
                numQueens++;
                found = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!found) {   //backtrack, pop the queen
            queens[numQueens - 1] = pop(&stack);
            numQueens--;
            row = queens[numQueens - 1].row + 1;
            if(numQueens <= numInitQ){  //there are not enough queens in total, therefore no solution
                printf("no solution\n");
                return;
            }
        } else {
            push(&stack, queens[numQueens - 1]);
            row++;
        }
    }

    // Print the solution
    for (int i = 0; i < numQueens; i++) {
        printf("%d %d\n", queens[i].row+1, queens[i].col+1);
    }
}


for testing, I have used the main function:
int main() {
    Queen initialQueens[] = { {0, 0} }; // Example initial queens
    int numInitialQueens = 1;
    int maxQueens = 4; // Change this to the board size
    solveQueens(maxQueens, initialQueens, numInitialQueens);
    return 0;
}

Which expectedly prints No Solution. However, when I try to make the board size 5 (setting maxQueens to 5) the function enters an infinite loop. My theory is that this is probably caused by the function finding a valid queen, but the total number of queens is not enough, which causes it to backtrack repeatedly. Don't take my word for the error, I could be way off but it might be a lead. Anyone got any fixes and suggestions?
EDIT 1: So sorry that I left this out in the original question, I am trouble with specifically Queen initialQueens[] = { {0, 1}, {1,5} } and Queen initialQueens[] = { {0, 0}, {1,4} } which is supposed to print a solution (I was given 1 2 2 5 3 3 4 1 5 4, ignore the formatting) and No solution respectively

If I fix your non-compiling code by renaming num_queens to numQueens, and making the suggested change of initializing maxQueens to 5, the program completes. Perhaps you have an unintentional error here from some other variable that you didn't show.

@paddy sorry this was an older version of the code, in the newer version everything compiles with the right names. but the infinite loop persists, that is the main problem.

You said that setting maxQueens to 5 creates this problem, yet with your new code, it still completes. However, using the main function as shown in the question (with maxQueens set to 4) does have a buffer underflow problem which is highlighted by the address sanitizer: https://godbolt.org/z/KxEdeKsMe

@paddy that was my mistake, I made some clarifications in my edit and a slight change to the code

I ran out of time. But if anyone still got an answer I'd be happy to accept.

N Queen Problem reference.  It's easy except for the diagonal attack directions.  Hence -- not so easy. :-)   Nice because the site has solutions in several programming languages, including C.

The mental arithmetic solution for a human of applying the knights move repeatedly will provide the OP with a simple test case that his program should easily reproduce.
